# How can I convert Decimal(c#) to INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND (oracle)?

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I hava a table in Oracle 11g:

```
----------------------------------------
|Field   |  Type                        |
|myField |  interval Day(0) to second(0)|
|myField2|  interval Day(0) to second(0)|
|myField3|  VARCHAR2(150 BYTE)          |
----------------------------------------
```

I have this mapping in Entity Framework 5

```
public class MyTable
{
    public Decimal? MyField { get; set; }
    public Decimal? MyField2 { get; set; }
    public String MyField3 { get; set; }
}

class MyTableMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyTable> {
    public MyTableMap ()
    {
        ToTable("myTabla");
        Property(u => u.MyField).HasColumnName("myField");
        Property(u => u.MyField2).HasColumnName("myField2");
        Property(u => u.MyField3).HasColumnName("myField3");
    }
}
```

So when he tried to change the field "MyFiel y MyFiel2" mark me the following error: "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details." and the innerException has null

when I change the "MyField3" field everything works fine

someone knows I'm doing wrong??

Comment: myField = interval Day(0) to second(0); myField2 = interval Day(0) to second(0); Field3 = VARCHAR2(150 BYTE)

Comment: Is not interval types mapped to TimeSpan? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e17732/featSafeType.htm#ODPNT429

Comment: if I put it "TimeSpan?" get other error 
Oracle Data Provider for .NET does not support Time

Comment: THIS IS THE QUERY
update "SISSEG." "SEGHORARIO"
set "DOMINGOFIN" =: p0
where ("IDHORARIO" =: p1)
Error Report -
SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent data types: expected INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND NUMBER has been obtained
00000 00932. - "inconsistent datatypes: expected% s% s got"

Comment: I have tested it with DevArt. It is actually 'decimal?' . May be the property in the edml file is not properly set. Generate the model from the DB. I have this <Property Name="TI" Type="interval day to second" Precision="6" Scale="6" />

Answer (score 0):

this es the solution with Fluent API

```
class MyTableMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyTable> {
    public MyTableMap ()
    {
        ToTable("myTabla");
        Property(u => u.MyField).HasColumnName("myField").HasColumnType("INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND");
        Property(u => u.MyField2).HasColumnName("myField2").HasColumnType("INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND");
        Property(u => u.MyField3).HasColumnName("myField3");
    }
}
```